# adding an IF to another file to communicate with functions.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been at this a few hours but can't figure it out. Basically I have

```
    function removed_user( $checkRemoved, $id ) { 
         global $wpdb; 
         global $current_user;
         $id = ThemexUser::$data['active_user']['ID'];
         $checkRemoved = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * from $wpdb->users WHERE ID = '%d' AND removed = '%d'", $id, '1' ));
                  }
do_action('remove_user');
           }
```

which is fine, then in my theme page I have

```
<?php do_action('removed_user'); ?>
```

I want to add an IF statement to my template file to show a message if the person has been removed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/

http://frumph.net/2010/06/14/understanding-do_action-and-add_action/

On these 2 pages you can see how you need to work with do_action.

BTW: You have 2 arguments in your function declaration. Your do_action calls only the function, but gives no parameters. That will give you an error. You need to either give arguments to your function or declare the parameters as optional with:

```
function removed_user ($checkRemoved = 0, $id = 0)
```

As far as I understand your function, you can remove the parameters, because you don't use them.

Comment: Thank Tim, I knew I had a couple of mistakes there, I didn't get around to re-posting. I'll give your link a look.